# Traducción al español de "Indian giver"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, coloquialismos, lenguaje-peyorativo

[Indian giver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_giver) es un término peyorativo que designa a alguien que te da un regalo y luego te lo quita o roba, lo pide de vuelta o pide otra cosa a cambio del "regalo".

Recuerdo que de niño mi hermano y yo usábamos la expresión "te lo *desregalo*" (algo típico de niños. Le das un regalo a alguien cuando estás de buenas, pero luego, si la persona te hace enfadar con "lógica infantil" piensas que ya no se merece ese regalo que le hiciste tiempo ha, y lo exiges de vuelta).

El término en inglés tiene una acepción un poco más amplia, porque puede referirse no solo a alguien que te pide el regalo de vuelta, sino a alguien que te hace el regalo para poder pedir un favor u otro tipo de regalo a cambio (un *interesado*).

Por su etimología, la expresión tiene fuertes connotaciones raciales, aparte de que su uso ya de por sí sea peyorativo.

¿Hay algún equivalente en español para "alguien que te hace un regalo por interés para pedir algo a cambio o que luego te quita el regalo que te ha hecho"?

Entiendo que en español la expresión, si existe, tendrá también connotaciones peyorativas, pero no estoy buscando necesariamente que las tenga, ni que tenga connotaciones raciales como el original.

Comment: ¿Raciales o racistas? // Lo que describiste de comprar un favor con un regalo se oye como *corrupción.*

Comment: Bueno, la original hace referencia a una raza (indios nativos americanos) de forma peyorativa, por lo que es "racista" aparte de una referencia racial. Como digo, entiendo que en español la expresión, probablemente, será peyorativa también, pero no estoy buscando nada que necesariamente lo sea, ni que necesariamente haga referencia a un colectivo por raza o etnia (digamos, cambiar los indios por gitanos). De serlo, dado el sentido de la expresión, creo que sería las dos cosas a la vez también, como el original.

Comment: En algunos casos podríamos usar la expresión *regalo envenenado*, cuando te refieres a uno que después va a acarrear consecuencias negativas. Pero no es una expresión que te sirva siempre, además de hacer referencia al regalo y no a quien lo hace.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/255284/112436

Answer (score 5):

Existe un dicho:

> El que da y quita, con el diablo se desquita.

Nada más.

Como probablemente ya sabes, "Indian giver" tiene origen en las prácticas agrícolas de las poblaciones indígenas en los Estados Unidos: ellos creían que la tierra le pertenecía a la tribu, y era prestada a los miembros de la tribu por un tiempo pero después estos la tenían que desocupar para que alguien más la pudiese utilizar. A los colonizadores, esto no les pareció y lo vieron como una afrenta a sus derechos de propiedad. El término es único tanto en su historia como en la connotación que ha adquirido de hipocresía accidental, ya que el gobierno de los Estados Unidos negociaba con las tribus indígenas la firma de tratados a través de los cuales se creaban las famosas reservas, otorgando a los nativos tierras a cambio de rendición. Pero cuando se encontraban minas de oro o plata en dichas reservas, el gobierno rompía sus propios tratados y en varias ocasiones masacraba a los indígenas si estos se oponían.

Entonces no solamente no hay un equivalente en español; no hay equivalente en ningún otro lenguaje. Muchos lenguajes tienen refranes o dichos, pero "Indian giver" nace de la noción singularmente estadounidense de que los derechos de propiedad privada deben prevalecer y triunfar sobre todo lo demás.

De hecho, el término es tan idiosincrático de los EUA, que incluso en el Reino Unido "Indian giver" significa algo completamente diferente: es un empleado en un restaurante Hindú de comida para llevar que regala papas, salsa, o pan naan, sin ninguna implicación de que tales regalos serán revocados.

Una forma correcta y respetuosa pero poco común de expresar lo que quieres decir es *Obsequiante no fidedigno.*

Para "Indian gift" podrías decir *regalo temporal.*

Y al acto de "Indian giving" podrías decirle *generosidad efímera.*

**Por cierto, todos estos son términos que también podrías usar en inglés sin ofender a nadie:** ***unreliable giver / temporary gift / short-lived generosity.***

Otra forma más coloquial sería *rajón.* Suele utilizarse para un hombre que está de acuerdo en hacer algo y luego cambia de opinión, pero también se puede utilizar para cualquier persona que no es fiable, incluyendo a las personas que "desregalan." 
El problema es que no es universal. Cada país de habla hispana tiene su propia palabra, pero todos tienden a acercarse al significado de cobardía. Por ejemplo, *rajón* puede ser más cercano en significado y en uso a *pussy* (cuando se refiere a un hombre), aunque menos ofensivo. Pero si es solo para molestar a un amigo, hermano, o colega, esa es la palabra más natural que se me ocurre.

Podrías empezar a decir "desregalador." Es incorrecto y nadie lo dice, pero todo hispanoparlante nativo entendería lo que quieres decir. ¿Y quien sabe? Tal vez se esparce y al rato todos lo decimos.

Comment: En chileno: "Al que da y quita le sale una jorobita" (o "...le sale una cutumita").

Answer (score 0):

En la canción de rock *Indian giver* del grupo  1910 Fruitgum Company, refiere la connotación de desregalo en el ámbito amoroso. Da amor o promete amor y luego lo quita, la letra así lo describe "Took back the love you gave to me…" Se presenta más como una traición amorosa. En México recuerdo que a esta canción la presentaban como "indio tracalero" que refiere más a una persona no confiable, tramposo, o ladrón. La referencia histórica que se hace me parece importante. Gracias por el referente.